# Deleting a QObject that QSharedPointer is pointing to

Tags: c++, qt, qsharedpointer

In my project I create `QObject` instances and give them a parent-child relationship. I also want to keep track of some of the objects with `QSharedPointer` instances.

When an object gets deleted, either by `delete childObject;` or `delete parentObject;`, I would like the `QSharedPointer` instances to return `true` when calling `isNull()`.

However, upon deleting any object `QSharedPointer` points to, my program crashes.

Here is my code:

```
QObject *child = new QObject();
QSharedPointer<QObject> ptr(child);
delete child;
```

This alone crashes my program. I read the documentation for `QSharedPointer` and it states `A QSharedPointer object can be created from a normal pointer` so I'm a bit confused as to why `QSharedPointer` can't handle the object pointed to being deleted.

`QPointer` doesn't have this problem, and I can even call `isNull()`, however the reason I need `QSharedPointer` is because some child objects will be created and not given a parent, at which point I want the child object to be deleted when all relevant `QSharedPointers` go out of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QSharedPointer takes ownership of the raw pointer that you pass to it. That means once all shared pointers go out of scope it will delete the object it points to. If you already manually delete an object then that will lead to a double free which causes a crash (if you are lucky!).

With a shared pointer you don't have to manually call delete at all as that will happen automatically as mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks. However when I call delete on the parent object, the children also get deleted. This is the crux of my problem. It seems I can't let the parents and QSharedPointer both handle the children right?

Comment: @mrg95 You need to decide which way of managing resources to choose. If you want to go the shared pointer way then just don't give the children objects any parent.

Comment: Do you think there is any way to detect and prevent QSharedPointer from doing that second delete? Subclass perhaps?

Comment: @mrg95 No, the whole point of QSharedPointer is to do exactly that once all instances go out of scope.

Comment: Okay sounds like I'll have to store the child objects in a QVector or something inside the parent objects... Thanks for the help! :)